# String with letter giving me a number in Ruby-Processing

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

I'm following [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/process_artist.html) to learn about creating shapes and colors on a canvas. Here is the issue I'm running into: When I try to run the command in the run_command method and I take the first letter of my command (command[0]), it is returning the number 98 to me. I am trying to match the first letter of the command to a letter of the alphabet, but am unable to do so. What's strange though, is that when I remove the first letter with "command.delete "b"", the letter is removed and I'm free to use the rest of the string as I please.

Here is my code:

```
require 'ruby-processing'
class ProcessArtist < Processing::App

  def setup
    background(0, 0, 0)
  end

  def draw
    # Do Stuff
  end

  def key_pressed
    if @queue.nil?
      @queue = ""
    end
    if key != "\n"
      @queue = @queue + key
    else
      warn "Time to run the command: #{@queue}"
      run_command(@queue)
      @queue = ""
    end
  end

  def run_command(command)
    puts "Running command: #{command}"
    puts command[0]
    if command[0] == "b"
      command.delete "b"
      command.split(",")
      background(command[0].to_i,command[1].to_i,command[2].to_i)
    else
      puts command[0]
      command.delete "b"
      command.split(",")
      background(command[0].to_i,command[1].to_i,command[2].to_i)
    end
  end
end

ProcessArtist.new(:width => 800, :height => 800,
                  :title => "ProcessArtist", :full_screen => false)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using ruby version older than *1.9*.

In old version of ruby (1.8-), [`String#\[\]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) return `Fixnum` object representing ASCII value, not `String` object.

```
>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "1.8.7"
>> 'bcd'[0]
=> 98
```

To get string back, use one of followings:

```
>> 'bcd'[0,1]
=> "b"
>> 'bcd'[0..0]
=> "b"
>> 'bcd'[0].chr # this will not work in Ruby 1.9+, so not recommended.
=> "b"
```

For comparison:

```
>> 'bcd'[0] == 'b'
=> false
>> 'bcd'[0] == ?b
=> true
>> 'bcd'.start_with? 'b'
=> true
```

Comment: Ah, that is very helpful. Thank you. It also seems that I should not have been using an "==" as a comparative operator and instead just used if command[0] = "b" then....

Comment: That's awesome, thank you. Which of the last two would you recommend using? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to private message you, but is there an easy way to upgrade my Ruby version on Windows that you know of?

Comment: @stytown, `start_with?` only can be used for the first character.

Comment: @stytown, I don't know easy way. I'll delete old version, install new version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40702/discussion-between-stytown-and-falsetru)

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I see what I did wrong. It should have been:

```
def run_command(command)
    puts "Running command: #{command}"
    puts command[0]
    if command[0] = "b"
      command.delete "b"
      command.split(",")
      background(command[0].to_i,command[1].to_i,command[2].to_i)
    else
      puts command[0]
      command.delete "b"
      command.split(",")
      background(command[0].to_i,command[1].to_i,command[2].to_i)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you mean `if command[0] = "b"` ? Then, `else` block will never be executed.

Comment: You're right. It's strange, command[0] is still returning 98. I've tried all of your suggestions and I'm also using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: Put `puts RUBY_VERSION` in your script. Check the output it prints.